# Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".vbs"

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, file-extension, vbscript

I keep getting it in command prompt, any idea why and how I may resolve the issue?

Windows 7 Ultimate 32-Bit

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: try running it this way cscript sript.vbs if there is a different error please post that one too.

Comment: Did this start after you installed some software? If so, try reinstalling it.

Comment: this is a similar question to http://superuser.com/questions/223728/windows-script-host-error-dialog-popups-in-the-morning
There are other answers in that thread that are not mentioned here.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this first.

Open an elevated Command Prompt window. To do so, click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator. Type the following command in the Command Prompt window, and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\vbscript.dll
```

You should see the following message:

> DllRegisterServer in vbscript.dll succeeded.

Now see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the file associations?

http://www.nilpo.com/2009/07/windows-xp/restoring-vbs-vbscript-script-file-file-associations/

Comment: File associations is a good guess. In my case it was that Notepad++ was trying to handle .js files.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Windows remote management is installed, and reinstall the WSH configuration settings:

1. Find the Windows/inf directory.

   - Enter `%windir%\inf` into the run, command-line, or Explorer address field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this directory is commonly located at `C:\WINDOWS\inf`)
2. This directory is hidden;  unhide as follows:

   - Tools → Folder Options → View → Advanced Settings
   - Uncheck "Hide protected operating system files"
3. Within the inf directory, find the "wsh.inf" file.
4. Right-click on the file and select Install.
5. Retest the scripting engine.
6. This will restore these files:

   - .js
   - .jse
   - .wsh
   - .vbs
   - .vbe
   - .wsc
   - .wsf

Comment: Hi, I don't see any wsh.inf file. What could I do in this scenario?