# There is no script engine for file extension ".vbs"

Tags: google-drive, vbscript

Google Drive occasionally pops up this error, randomly with no obvious cause:

> --------------------------- Windows Script Host ---------------------------
>   There is no script engine for file extension ".vbs".
>   --------------------------- OK    ---------------------------

Is something misconfigured on my computer?

Comment: [You have not provided enough information to conclude the reason you can't run .VBS files on your system](http://superuser.com/questions/155929/input-error-there-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension-vbs?rq=1) common enough problem though.

Comment: @Ramhound Aha.  http://superuser.com/a/223757/13889 shows that Notepad++ is claiming the file extension so it doesn't really have anything to do with Google Drive?

Comment: Google Drive is attempting to execute the .VBS its unable to do so if you have it assigned to Notepad++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by associating ***.vbs*** files with `Notepad++` (or in some cases, perhaps a different program). You could be able to solve it by running `Notepad++` as an administrator and removing the file association for *.vbs* files.

If you're not sure which program is causing the problem, you can find out by searching for

> "Change the file type associated with a file extension"

from the start menu. To fix the problem from there, make sure that .vbs files have `Microsoft Windows Based Script Host` set as the current default program.

In addition, to set `Microsoft Windows Based Script Host (Wscript.exe)` set as the current default program, you can follow the command below: `"cscript.exe //H:WScript"`.

If this issue still persists, please also try to reassociate the vbs files with ".vbs":

```
assoc .vbs=VBSFile
```

Refer to:

http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html