# How to reinstall broken VBScript support on Windows XP SP3?

Tags: windows-xp, vbscript, wsh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension “.vbs”.](https://superuser.com/questions/155929/input-error-there-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension-vbs)

VBScript support (Windows Scripting Host, as far as I understand) seems to be been broken on my system (for example, when I run a Microsoft FixIt tool it doesn't work and complains that "There is no script engine for file extension `.vbs`."). I've found [Windows Script 5.7 for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=8247) but it refuses to install saying I have a newer service pack already installed. How to repair VBScript then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to repair the WMI.
Do this:

Open a command promt (cmd) and run the following commands, one by one.

```
rundll32 wbemupgd, UpgradeRepository
cd /d %windir%\system32\wbem
for %i in (*.dll) do RegSvr32 -s %i
for %i in (*.exe) do %i /RegServer
```

Reboot computer.

http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm

Comment: Excuse me, colleagues, but even though I accept the solution, I can't testify that ti works. Unfortunately I can't remember whether or not it had helped me but tend to believe it had.